# INSERT unique rows taken from the same table with a changed column

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, unique-constraint, upsert

I have a table `table_1` in Postgres with three columns based on a Django model, `ID` (auto incrementing value), `affiliation`, and `entry`.

What I need to do is take every entry where `affiliation = 52`, and then add an additional row with `entry = query.entry` and `affiliation = 48`. I need additional rows, not changed values. I also need to make sure that the entry + affiliation pair does not exist already.

My latest attempt:

```
do $$
declare
id_array int[];
begin
insert into id_array table_1.entry where table_1.affiliation = 52;
for id in id_array
loop
if not exists (select entry from table_1 where affiliation = 48)
then 
insert into table_1 (affiliation, entry) values (48, id);
else
raise notice "already exists";
end if;
endloop;
end; $$
```

I still get a syntax error! Any ideas? I'm at a complete loss. This is by far the most complex query I've ever tried.

Comment: Add the syntax error to your question. Though I'm going to say the issue is here: `insert into id_array  ...`. If I'm following correctly that probably should be: `select into id_array array_agg(entry)  from table1 where affiliation = 52;`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a (clumsy and inefficient, and incorrect) loop for this.

You should have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(affiliation, entry)` to begin with.

#### With `UNIQUE` index

With a `UNIQUE` constraint or index on `(affiliation, entry)` just use an "UPSERT":

```sql
INSERT INTO table_1 (affiliation, entry)
SELECT 48, entry
FROM   table_1
WHERE  affiliation = 52
ON     CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

`ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` skips any would-be duplicate. Job done.

This is safe against race conditions under concurrent write load.
See:

- [How to UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)

#### Without `UNIQUE` index

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 48, t1.entry
FROM   table_1 t1
LEFT   JOIN table_1 t2 ON t2.entry = t1.entry
                      AND t2.affiliation = 48
WHERE  t1.affiliation = 52
AND    t2.entry IS NULL;  -- does not exist yet
```

I added `DISTINCT` as without said `UNIQUE` index, there might be duplicates on `(affiliation, entry)` to begin with, and we don't want  more than one copy.

Not safe against race conditions under concurrent write load.

See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Both queries assume `entry` to be defined `NOT NULL`. Else you need to define how to deal with `NULL` values.